# Why does the boot partition under a BIOS-GPT configuration need to be 1007KiB?

Tags: boot, partitioning, gpt

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_.28GPT.29_specific_instructions

Other sources may refer 1MiB for it, but I'm really curious about this Magic Number. Why not 1000KiB plus a 24KiB gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced quote refers to a [BIOS Boot Partition,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition) which holds BIOS-mode GRUB code. The wiki you cited does a poor job of explaining the issue. There is no "magic size" for a BIOS Boot Partition, because the GRUB code it holds can vary in size depending on the version of GRUB being used and the specific features (such as filesystem drivers) that must be included in that code set. In the past, 33KiB was big enough, but in many cases today it needs to be larger than that. I've seen claims that some installations actually need more than 1MiB, but I've never verified this myself.

It appears that the Arch wiki authors are overly concerned with optimizing disk layout; they seem to want there to be no unallocated sectors on the disk. To accomplish this goal, they're advocating creating a strangely-sized BIOS Boot Partition so that it completely occupies all the space between sector 34 (the first available sector under GPT, assuming standard partition table size) and 2047 (the final sector before sector 2048, which is the default first sector used, given 2048-sector alignment). There's nothing wrong with doing it this way, assuming the GRUB code fits in 1007KiB; but if you were to accept default 2048-sector alignment on all partitions, including the BIOS Boot Partition, the result would simply be 1007KiB of unallocated disk space and a reduction in size of one data partition by 1MiB compared to doing it as the wiki suggests. Given that modern disks have capacities that are measured in terabytes (in other words, *millions of times* larger than the wasted space), this obsession with preserving 1MiB of space is, IMHO, misplaced.

Comment: Thanks, Rod! Clear and informative answer! I just read about the articles you wrote about gdisk yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know from where are you got this "24KiB" and "1000KiB" numbers. The bootpartition is so big, to all possible bootloader code, configfile, helpfile, kernelimage, etc. had its place in it. This 1Meg is imho little, becuase

- kernels can be today even 20megs or so
- its size need to be overdeclared, because
- making place on the *beginning* of a hard disk, thus moving the *beginning* of the first real data partition, is mostly one of the hardest repartitioning operations,
- even this really big boot partitions will be small comparised with the hard disk sizes of today (f.e. 200 meg is practically nothing on a 4T disk).

Comment: The reference is to a BIOS Boot Partition, which is different from an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) to which your comments apply.

Comment: I guess your suggestion is about giving /boot a separate partition and it should be 200MiB, thank you all the same! Rod is right, I'm asking this question under a very specific (even rare?) situation.